# Java JSR documents

Tags: java

I often see the frequent use of a "JSR-XXX" title when mentioning various aspects of Java and JSPs and JSF. JSR-299 for CDI?, or JSR-303 for some annotations for example.

Is it relevant/important to learn these concepts by their "JSR" name ? Even if it isn't, where can I find a comprehensive list of all of these documents ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The JSRs are all listed here: http://jcp.org/en/jsr/all

I would say that it is not very important to know the concepts by the JSR identifier, unless you are interested in becoming an early adopter of whatever technology is being built to fulfill the JSR.  I personally don't find it all that useful to refer to the features by JSR identifier in very many cases.

Comment: Indeed: the "R" in "JSR", meaning Request, indicates that such a document is at most a preview or (in some cases) draft of new features in Java.

Answer (score 0):

I still believe that it is important to have some knowledge of JSRs. This is where the inception of most common JAVA APIs happen.

In a nutshell there are some companies like Oracle, SUN(few years back), IBM, BEA, Exhadel etc gather and **request** "there is a need of an API or framework which does x, y and z" these requests are taken through JSR process and if finalized they are implemented.

For example inception of JSF 2.0 happened from JSR 314, it was only then vendors came up with real frameworks like icefaces or richfaces supporting the JSR.

Nevertheless, there is no need of knowing JSRs for your day to day programming but some knowledge of them will keep you updated with what path the Java community is taking and what can you expect from newer versions of Java based technologies.
Thanks